# Windows server 2016 - Add a user that will have the same programs and settings like my user

Tags: windows, active-directory, windows-server-2016

I have my admin user account and it has some programs installed and IIS with all the configured websites.

How can I add another user to this server that will have all the programs that are already installed for my user + IIS configuration?

So far I tried to add another user using the add a new user account but when I logged in with that user it had no programs installed and IIS wasn't configured the same as my admin user.

Thank you

Comment: Most software is installed on the system, not user. Same goes for IIS which is a system service.
You could look into if any of the methods at https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/all/copying-user-profile-or-cloning-a-user-account/06aac64f-d1d8-4eb9-bea2-7a55a1a6b04f could be used. But I would strongly suggest that you start over and take this opportunity to document any changes and why. That way you will have documentation to fall back to when you need a reinstall after a crash or upgrade..

Comment: you may copy the user folder and overtake with that action any shortcuts

Comment: The IIS config is a server-wide config.  So long as the user has admin access to the server they'll be able to config IIS